# What is the most idiomatic way to index an object with a boolean array in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am particularly talking about Pandas version 0.11 as I am busy replacing my uses of .ix with either .loc or .iloc. I like the fact that differentiating between .loc and .iloc communicates whether I am intending to index by label or integer position. I see that either one will accept a boolean array as well but I would like to keep their usage pure to clearly communicate my intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 11.0 all three methods work, the way [suggested in the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#indexing-selection) is simply to use `df[mask]`. However, this is *not* done on position, but purely using labels, so in my opinion `loc` best describes what's actually going on.

*Update: I asked on [github](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3631) about this, the conclusion being that `df.iloc[msk]` will give a `NotImplementedError` (if integer indexed mask) or `ValueError` (if non-integer indexed) in pandas `11.1`.*

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(range(5), list('ABCDE'), columns=['a'])

In [2]: mask = (df.a%2 == 0)

In [3]: mask
Out[3]:
A     True
B    False
C     True
D    False
E     True
Name: a, dtype: bool

In [4]: df[mask]
Out[4]:
   a
A  0
C  2
E  4

In [5]: df.loc[mask]
Out[5]:
   a
A  0
C  2
E  4

In [6]: df.iloc[mask]  # Due to this question, this will give a ValueError (in 11.1)
Out[6]:
   a
A  0
C  2
E  4
```

Perhaps worth noting that if you gave mask integer index it would throw an error:

```
mask.index = range(5)
df.iloc[mask]  # or any of the others
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided
```

*This demonstrates that iloc isn't actually implemented, it uses label, hence why 11.1 will throw a `NotImplementedError` when we try this.*

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't considered the .iloc behaviour with an integer index. To be honest I had actually forgotten that mask has an .index attribute in this case, I was thinking of it as purely a boolean numpy array. I agree that given that the .index attribute is actually used to do an alignment first, .loc is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using `[]`, i.e. `__getitem__()`, e.g.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(a=range(5)))
df[df.a%2==0]
```

Comment: Don't use the `dict` constructor, use `{'a': range(5)}` it looks much nicer

Comment: dict literals also happen to be a lot faster.

Comment: Good to know about the speed difference. I prefer the look of the `dict` constructor and also like that I don't have to put quotes around the keyword arguments which makes typing easier. However if the speed difference is big then perhaps I will switch to dict literals.